# MVVM Drag&Drop on all Window with effect

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I've got a window

[image]

and i want to implement the drag and drop on it to handle dropping meda. How can I do this while keeping with the MVVM pattern?

Comment: Drag & drop is a UI concern.  Handle that in your codebehind.  Expose a property on your window, such as string[] DroppedFile, then bind it to your view model.  When that changes, handle it in your VM.

Answer (score -1):

I recently added drag & drop functionality to a WPF application using Gong Solution drag and drop for WPF. Very easy implementation and well documented. It requires installing the package (you can use Nuget Package Console) and adding a reference in your xaml file. Check it out and let me know if you need greater explanation:

https://github.com/punker76/gong-wpf-dragdrop